# How to use a slider to set values within the backend of my C# code

Tags: c#, wpf, variables, slider

Here is a snippet of my code of what I have tried so far.

At the moment I have succesfully binded the value of the slider to a textbox. I want to bind this same value to a variable within my code. Such as when the slide position is at 1.5. The calculation within the code will use the value 1.5. The variable which I required to be updated is the flslidervalue. But after my research online, I've learnt that I would need to use a double due to the fact that my slider numbers contain decimals.

Below is a snippet of my code with the relevant parts:

```
    float flradius;
    float flfactual;
    float flfmax;
    float flfos;
    float slvalue;

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        flfactual = flfmax / flfos;


        //output Flfmax back to form
        txtFmax.Text = flfmax.ToString();

        //output Flfactual back to form
        txtFactual.Text = flfactual.ToString();


    }

    private void fosslider_ValueChanged(
        object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        txtSlider.Text = fosslider.Value.ToString();
        Double slvalue = fosslider.Value.To
    }
```

---

XAML CODE

```
 <Slider x:Name="fosslider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="403,258,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="246" TickPlacement="BottomRight" Maximum="4" SmallChange="0.5" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" ValueChanged="fosslider_ValueChanged" LargeChange="0.5" TickFrequency="0.5" />
 <TextBox x:Name="txtSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="431,310,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here that you need to know how to convert a string to a double and store it as a global variable.

It looks like you were almost there:

```
float flradius;
float flfactual;
float flfmax;
float flfos;
float slvalue;
double flslidervalue; //Create the global variable so it's accessible from 
                      //all methods

private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    flfactual = flfmax / flfos;

    //output Flfmax back to form
    txtFmax.Text = flfmax.ToString();

    //output Flfactual back to form
    txtFactual.Text = flfactual.ToString();
}

private void fosslider_ValueChanged(object sender, 
                                    RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    txtSlider.Text = fosslider.Value.ToString();

    //Add this line, this will parse your string to a double that you can 
    //access by calling flslidervalue 
    Double.TryParse(fosslider.Value.ToString(), out flslidervalue); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much!! It worked perfectly. I also had to change the variable flfactual to a double as the valued which i required to be changed with the slider was 'flfos'. Once again. Thank you. Also why did my post get 5 downvotes? Is there something I did wrong? lol

Comment: Great! I can only speculate that it was down voted because it was not very clear what you were asking.